# My SoapExtension is receiving the AfterSerialize message twice!

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, visual-studio-2010, soap

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and C# to write a web service that requires special handling that I'm solving by rolling my own SoapExtension. This SoapExtension is of course implementing the *ProcessMessage* method.

This is all fine, but for some reason this *ProcessMessage* is being called twice (two, 2 times) for each of the Stages of the SoapServerMessage and that is my problem. Any help with figuring out why this is and how I can make it only be called once (one, 1 time), would be highly appreciated.

BTW: I have found others on the web that have been having a similar problem, like this [guy at mofeel.com](http://www.mofeel.net/55-microsoft-public-dotnet-framework-aspnet-webservices/2202.aspx), which indicates that he found the solution [here at experts-exchange.com](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_22045885.html) but I will not give out my creditcard for the solution. That is a principle. Can someone help me, please?

My *ProcessMessage* method looks like this:

```
public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
{
    if (message is SoapServerMessage)
    {
        LogFile.WriteLogString(0, "-------------------");
        LogFile.WriteLogString(0, "message.Type:" + message.GetType().ToString());
        LogFile.WriteLogString(0, "message.Stage:" + message.Stage);
        LogFile.WriteLogString(0, "message.Stream.Length:" + message.Stream.Length);
        LogFile.WriteLogString(0, "message.Stream.Position:" + message.Stream.Position);
        LogFile.WriteLogString(0, "message.Exception:" + message.Exception);
        ProcessServerMessage(message);
    }
    else ProcessClientMessage(message);
}
```

...and when I make a single call to my web method I get a log looking like this:

```
7.7.2010 17:40:25: -------- Log file opened --------
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] -------------------
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Type:System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerMessage
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stage:BeforeDeserialize
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Length:0
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Position:0
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Exception:
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] -------------------
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Type:System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerMessage
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stage:BeforeDeserialize
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Length:0
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Position:0
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Exception:
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] -------------------
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Type:System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerMessage
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stage:AfterDeserialize
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Length:330
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Position:330
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Exception:
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] -------------------
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Type:System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerMessage
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stage:AfterDeserialize
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Length:330
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Position:330
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Exception:
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] -------------------
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Type:System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerMessage
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stage:BeforeSerialize
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Length:0
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Position:0
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Exception:
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] -------------------
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Type:System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerMessage
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stage:BeforeSerialize
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Length:0
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Position:0
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Exception:
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] -------------------
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Type:System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerMessage
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stage:AfterSerialize
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Length:480
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Position:480
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Exception:
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] -------------------
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Type:System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerMessage
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stage:AfterSerialize
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Length:480
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Stream.Position:480
7.7.2010 17:40:27: [0] message.Exception:
```

Notice how every message stage is being called twice?!?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two possiblities here.

1- You have configured the soap extension in the web.config and you have a custom SoapExtensionAttribute that you applied to the web method.

This would essentially configure the SoapExtension twice and therefore it will run once because of the configuration in the web.config and a second time because of the attribute applied to the web method.

2- You have actually configured the soap extension twice in the web.config.

Comment: Thanks a million. You are right, I had it in the web.config file as well as applied the attribute.